# Laravel 5.7 - Many To Many Relation - Select Movies which have the provided array of Genre IDs

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, model

This is my controller code:

```
if ($request->genre && !$request->search) {
    $genres = explode(',', $request->genre);
    return Movie::with('genres')->whereHas('genres', function ($q) use ($genres) {
        return $q->whereIn('id', $genres);
    })->paginate(10);
}
```

My pivot table contains movie_id and genre_id. Both movies and genres tables do not contain reference of ID of each other.

I would need to select all movies from the table which have genres selected by the user.

For example, an array of `id's = [1, 4, 9]` and to select from pivot table movies that contain those genre ids.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**
General problem was `return` inside callback and the way I handled data later on. Thanks for your answers, I appreciate it! :)

Comment: So what's with your code? Doesn't it work?

Comment: I think you might just need to remove the `return` in your `whereHas()` query.

Answer (score 0):

You did a wrong query, try the given query.

```php
return Movie::with(['genres'])->whereHas('genres' ,function ($query) use ($genres){
    $query->whereIn('id', $genres);
})->paginate(10);
```

Comment: This will also get any movies that *doesn't* have those generes though, but it will just not be a part of the relation.

Comment: @Qirel Thanks, Now it should work. The question has only error as it's `return` inside query. :-)